# Why is scanf(); skipping the first line?

Tags: c, string, scanf

So after scanf, the `printf();` skips the first line 
I have read some questions that tells that ,  `"%[^\n]"` must be `" %[^\n]"` to skip the newline. 
 
I have tried it both, but it still print the same result and now I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
Example input
Enter number of Materi: 4
Materia 1 name : a
Materia 2 name : b
materia 3 name : c
materia 4 name : d

Output:
Materia - 1 : R╒fu
Materia - 2 : a
Materia - 3 : b
Materia - 4 : c
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

    int i;
    int V;

    printf("Enter number of Materi: ");
    scanf("%d", &V); fflush(stdin);

    //Insert materia
    char materia[V][50];
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        printf("Materia %d name : ", i+1);scanf("%[^\n]", &materia[i][50]);fflush(stdin);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        printf("Materia - %d: %s\n", i+1, materia[i]);
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior in c, and useless where defined by POSIX or Windows. `scanf("%[^\n]", &materia[i][50])` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @EOF It actually ask to scan after i use fflush(stdin); , when i don't use it, it won't even scan at all

Comment: You don't (reasonably) control your input. You *can* control your output.

Comment: Add a space to `"%[^\n]"` making it `" %[^\n]"` and this will filter leading whitespace. It is not automatic with this format (or with `%c`).

Comment: @WeatherVane Do you mean, it is not possible to use within the ```for``` format ?

Comment: I mean add the space as recommended. Format specs `%d` and `%s` and `%f` automatically filter out leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. The `scanf` functions stop at the first character they cannot convert, which is left in the input buffer. You told `%[]` to stop at the first newline. There is one already there, from the first `%d` `scanf` and it needs to be removed, also in subsequent iterations and adding the space does that job. Trying to remove it *afterward* is clumsy and not guranteed to work.

Comment: @WeatherVane i have tried adding space ``` %[^\n]```, but it still prints the same output
edited: oops i mean [^\n]

Comment: That does not look like `" %[^\n]"`. The `^` is missing. Also, remove the `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: There is another mistake: `&materia[i][50]` should be `materia[i]`

Comment: @WeatherVane oh wait, what
it works after i change ```&materia[i][50]``` to ```materia[i]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the program

- The array passed to `scanf` is wrong.
- `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard, although Windows does support it it's not portable. But you aren't using Windows because it does not support the VLA `char materia[V][50];`
- The newlines which the `scanf` format `"%[^\n]"` will stop at, are already the next character in the input buffer.
- The return value from `scanf` was not checked. It is the number of items successfully scanned.
- You can have buffer overflow because the input string length is not restricted.

Here is the adjusted code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

    int i;
    int V;

    printf("Enter number of Materi: ");
    if(scanf("%d", &V) != 1) {
        /* add some error message */
        return 1;
    }
    // fflush(stdin);               // removed

    //Insert materia
    char materia[V][50];
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        printf("Materia %d name : ", i+1);
        // add a space to filter the newline
        // correct the array passed
        // and restrict the length to prevent buffer overflow
        if(scanf(" %49[^\n]", materia[i]) != 1) {
            /* add some error message */
            return 1;
        }
        // fflush(stdin);           // removed
    }

    for(i = 0; i < V; i++){
        printf("Materia - %d: %s\n", i+1, materia[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

About the newlines. Format specs `%d` and `%s` and `%f` automatically filter out leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. The `scanf` functions stop at the first character they cannot convert, which is left in the input buffer. The `%[^\n]` tell it to stop at the first newline. But there is one already there, from the first `%d` scanf and it needs to be removed, also in subsequent iterations and adding the space does that job. Trying to remove it afterward is clumsy and not guranteed to work.

You must check the return value from `scanf` every time it is used. It is the number of items successfully scanned. Here, it should be `1` in both uses. So if you have two items in one statement, its return value must be `2`.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &V);` -> Perhaps a check for the return value?

Comment: I would change "Ideally" to "you should"

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &materia[i][50]);
```

You are storing the inputed string in the address of `materia[i][50]`, effectively storing it outside the bounds of the array.

Something interesting happens here, 2D array storage is contiguous as if it was a one dimensional vector, what happens is you are storing the first string in the beginning of the second line of the array, the second on the third and so on, leaving the first empty. That's the rational for the output the program produces.

Correct you code with:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

//...

if(scanf(" %49[^\n]", materia[i] != 1) {
   puts("Read error");
   return EXIT_FAILURE;       
}
```

49 character + the nul terminator to avoid overflow, a space in the beginning of the specifier avoids the consuption of blank characters left in the `stdin` buffer. Always verify `scanf` return to avoid reading errors.

Some other issues:

- `fflush(stdin)` should be removed as [`fflush` is meant to be called on an output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/6865932).
- Variable lenght arrays can cause  stack overflow if enough memory is consumed, in this case it's not likely, but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. The newline character is consumed as a character by your subsequent `scanf`. That's why you are facing this problem.

Comment: is there a way to still use the ```scanf``` ?

Comment: You can call `getchar()` to consume the newline character if you want to continue using `scanf`.

Comment: "That's why you are facing this problem." Spoiler: It's not.

Comment: @EOF, care to elaborate on the spoiler?

Comment: @VHS hmm, I have tried adding ```getchar();``` after every scanf, but it still don't works.

Comment: @VHS Both comments on the question and another answer have found it, and it's also visible in the example input and output in given in the question.

Comment: @ChristianHalim forget trying to bodge the removal of the *next* character. One reason why that might not work is if the user types one or more spaces after the numeric input. Focus on filtering the *leading* whitespace before an input, which is simple.

Comment: @WeatherVane okay, what i read seems true about giving space on ``` %[^\n]```, the ```materia[i][50]``` is supposed to be changed to ```materia[i]```

Comment: You need both those changes, which are unrelated.

Comment: @WeatherVane which does both changes refers to ? the ```whitespace``` and the ```material[i]``` ?